# Customer Community - access to own Contact object?

Tags: community, licenses, customer-community

Can users of Salesforce "Customer Communities" update their own Contact object?

This Salesforce help page implies that they can:

[Salesforce - Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US)

[image]

This great diagram by Steven Herod implies that they only have Read-only access to their own contact record:

[LimitException - Salesforce Standard Object Access by Community or Portal license type](http://limitexception.herod.net/2013/08/28/salesforce-object-type-by-community-or-portal-type/)

Which is correct?

Comment: the help link states as well: "Contacts - Read Only access to their own contact" for customer community

Comment: @Seb_Wagner The help link has Accounts marked as 'Read Only' but not Contacts. See screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today, Customer Community users can edit their contact record if you setup sharing sets to give them this capability. The problem is the out of the box UI doesn't expose the contact to the user. You can expose via Visualforce. In the Spring '14 release Salesforce removes this restriction and the out of the box UI will now show both the Contact tab and record.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer. I see you work for Salesforce so I'll take that as definitive!

Comment: Ah yes I see it in the release notes https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf page 110. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get this working in a Spring 2014 Sandbox, thanks very much for the pointers.